# What is the best javascript charting library with bi-directional communication capability?

Tags: javascript, charts, data-visualization

Here is what I mean. I want to use charts not only for visualization but also as a source of user input, when the underlying model is updated based on user interacting with a chart. The use cases are:

- User highlights an area on a chart containing time series, and the data, which fits into this area gets displayed in a table
- User can swipe the whole time series chart to the right and the part of the chart starts displaying earlier data
- User can zoom in and out, and the table nearby gets updated
- User can drag a point on a curve up and down; and underlying model will change
- Same for pie charts
- User can enable and disable certain curves by clicking checkboxes inside the legend
- User can select an item in a stack chart; and this item is rendered as a pie chart nearby.

I am looking for a relatively high level of abstraction, not a low level graphical framework. Proven interoperability with AngularJS is also highly desired.

Comment: "What's the best..." questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You really want a library that is flexible with visualization. I think your best bet is d3js. I can perform most of the features you listed. Here are some examples of what it can do:

http://vida.io/explore

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

You can combine your d3js with other JS frameworks like Angular JS. See this example:

http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/5372077